# Read uploaded xlsx file from Restful backend java

Tags: java, ajax, rest, resteasy

I am uploading excel file from my UI via ajax-post call and try to read that from my backed Restful service java code but i cant print the excel file contents correctly.
File name and other attributes are printing correctly .

File uploaded : test.xlsx

Error if I use below code

```
[java] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionAdapter:  : null
```

POI version: 3.8

**upload.java**

```
public Response upload(final MultipartFormDataInput input)throws Exception{
    for (InputPart part : input.getParts()) { // you might get multiple files
        final String disposition = part.getHeaders().getFirst("Content-Disposition");
        final String fileName =  disposition.replaceFirst("(?i)^.*filename=\"([^\"]+)\".*$", "$1");
        InputStream inputStream = part.getBody(FileInputStream.class, null);
        try {
            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
            Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
                    if (currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                        System.out.print(currentCell.getStringCellValue() + "--");
                    } else if (currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        System.out.print(currentCell.getNumericCellValue() + "--");
                    } else if(currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                        System.out.print(currentCell.getBooleanCellValue() + "--");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("<BLANK>--");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    input.close();
    return Response.ok("OK").build();
}
```

If i use

> InputStream inputStream = part.getBody(InputStream.class, null);` 
>   then i get following error
>
> ```
>  [java] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
> ```

But if read excel file directly it is working fine

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown? What version of Poi are you using?

Comment: @DavidConrad : I edited the question please check

Comment: It sounds like the input stream is compressed or base64 encoded or in some other way needs further processing before it can be passed to Poi, but this is just a guess. I suggest you copy the entire contents of the stream to the log, to the console, or to a file, so that you can examine them.

Comment: You might need to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23253100/4039840) your problem are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue we need to get excel stream  as

> ***File.class*** instead of ***InputStream.class***

```
public Response upload(final MultipartFormDataInput input)throws Exception{
    Map<String, List<InputPart>> formDataMap = input.getFormDataMap();
    File inputStream = formDataMap.get("files").get(0).getBody(File.class, null);
    String extraField = formDataMap.get("extraField").get(0).getBodyAsString();
    String CustomField =  formDataMap.get("CustomField").get(0).getBodyAsString();

    try {

        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            Row currentRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();

                if (currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    System.out.print(currentCell.getStringCellValue() + "--");
                } else if (currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                    System.out.print(currentCell.getNumericCellValue() + "--");
                } else if(currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                    System.out.print(currentCell.getBooleanCellValue() + "--");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("<BLANK>--");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    input.close();
    return Response.ok("OK").build();
}
```